# Installing Adobe Photoshop CS4 results in "Error 1603"

Tags: windows, photoshop-cs4

I tried to install Adobe Photoshop CS4 and Adobe Director 11.5 on my Windows 7 PC, but I got the error:

> **Adobe Anchor Service CS4**
>   Error:
>   Error 1603.

I had Adobe Flash Professional CS5 installed already, so maybe it had some influence on that?

But now everything that was installed by Adobe is deleted. (Except for Adobe Air, X reader, Shockwave Player & Flash Player).

I tried to use `AdobeCreativeSuiteCleanerTool` but it didn't work.